# How can I play MIDI tracks created using python-midi package?

Tags: python, api, midi

I want to create MIDI tracks in a Python program and be able to play them instantly (preferably without writing to disk). I have recently discovered the package [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) which looks great. However I haven't figured out how to play the tracks created with this package. Do I need an additional package? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution if anyone is interested:

I ended up using [mido](https://github.com/olemb/mido) for my Python MIDI API, with Pygame as the backend.
Works like a charm :)